# regular expression to match numbers of length 2 from given string

Tags: c#, regex

How can I create a regular expression that will match numbers of length 2 from a given string.

Example input:

```
givenpercentage@60or•70and 8090
```

Desired output:

```
60 70 80 90
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string x = "givenpercentage@60or•70and 8090";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d{2}");
foreach(Match m in r.Matches(x))
{
     string temp = m.Value;
     //Do something
}
```

`\d` -> only numbers

`{2}` -> 2 numbers only

Output will be:

```
60 70 80 90
```

Comment: why doesn't it return 09? What should i change if i wanted any 2 digits? i.e. 60 70 80 09 90

Comment: It doesn´t return 09 because it goes taking 2 numbers each time. To do what you say.. What I do is to only match a single number, then check if index + 1 is a number, if it is, get both, otherwise, dont take anything.